# how to fix redirect error on Php when application run locally

Tags: php, redirect, controller, xampp, wamp

I have this problem in redirect to admin controller. My first page is login page. I get user and password from user and when I click on submit it goes to :
[http://localhost:2020/taxiapp/admin/dashboard] and i get this error:"Object not found!"

in admin-login I use this code to post information to admin controller:

```
     if($user2)
    {
        redirect("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/taxiapp/admin/dashboard");
    }
```

Comment: At least share your code, It does not explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think you are not able to redirect to a specific page. To redirect in PHP. Try using the following code

```
header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/taxiapp/admin/dashboard");
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You’re missing a die or exit function afrer header function

Comment: My problem is not redirect syntax.I have changed port in xampp.I Put project folder in htdocs folder.when I redirect to admin controller it shows me 404 error page and say Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

Answer (score 0):

add like this,

```
redirect("admin/dashboard");
```

also, make sure your `base_url` like following

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].':'. $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].'/taxiapp/';
```

Comment: My problem is not redirect syntax.I have changed port in xampp.I Put project folder in htdocs folder.when I redirect to admin controller it shows me 404 error page and say Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error

Comment: you should add the port in the base_url, check my answer now.

Comment: I did this but I get this error:server IP address could not be found.

Comment: have you added `admin/dashboard` in routes.php .??

Comment: no.I replaced that with 
    redirect("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/taxiapp/admin/dashboard");

Comment: add following code in your `routes.php` 
`$route['admin/dashboard'] = 'admin/dashboard';`
i guess `admin` is your controller & `dashboard` is the method

Comment: dashboard is a method

Comment: yeah add `$route['admin/dashboard'] = 'admin/dashboard';` code in tour routes.php file and update the code as i mentioned in the answer

Comment: I do all of this.there is no changes.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] get localhost:2020 and does not need  any changes.what is your idea about .htaaccess?

Comment: this is:    deny from all

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly this same problem but it was on a live server with Ubuntu 16.x
This problem is with mod_rewrite and your .htaccess file. So make sure mod_rewrite is properly installed and set up... i did ***sudo a2enmod rewrite*** for that and restarted my server.

**Now the important part.**

First i changed my Virtualhost config with
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

by adding this at the very top after the VirtualHost *:80

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then created my application .htacess with nano /var/www/html/.htaccess in the root of my application folder with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

This should give you an idea on how to solve it in Xampp

Comment: You still have to search your files and replace taxiapp/admin/dashboard with /admin/dashboard, then put the files in the root folder.